# How to add duration to time_point?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I tried something like this:

```
using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
clock::time_point nowp = clock::now();
clock::time_point end = nowp + std::chrono::seconds(10);
time_t nowt =  clock::to_time_t ( nowp );
time_t endt =  clock::to_time_t ( end);
std::cerr  << " " << ctime(&nowt) << " " << ctime(&endt) << std::endl;
```

But it prints:

```
Sat Dec 16 15:06:43 2017
Sat Dec 16 15:06:43 2017
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do add ten seconds to now?

Comment: For me, your code works: `Sat Dec 16 16:26:27 2017
 Sat Dec 16 16:26:37 2017`

Comment: See [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for an easier way to print chrono objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem might be because `ctime` store result in some static storage and just returns the pointer to you.

So it overwrites one result with another one and prints it 2 times.
Order of operation is not fixed by the standard so what it does:

1. Call `ctime` with one argument, which saves representation in internal buffer and returns pointer to it.
2. Call `ctime` with another argument, which saves representation in the same internal buffer and returns pointer to it.
3. Prints value from both char*'s (actually the same pointer)

Solution is to force order of evaluation by dividing operations with `;`

Code that [fixes problem for me](https://ideone.com/ZbhJh7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    clock::time_point nowp = clock::now();
    clock::time_point end = nowp + std::chrono::seconds(10);
    time_t nowt =  clock::to_time_t ( nowp );
    time_t endt =  clock::to_time_t ( end);
    std::cout  << " " << ctime(&nowt) << "\n";
    std::cout << ctime(&endt) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```